# Problems with setting up pybrain on Mac through Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, enthought, pybrain

I'm trying to setup Pybrain on my Mac for the past couple of days but to no avail.
I downloaded the Enthought Canopy and I have made sure that it is my default python. I also tried the suggestions given on the Pybrain documentary page but I did not find a solution to my problem.

I'm a beginner to installing other files for python and setting them up on the Mac, so forgive me if I might sound stupid.

I have also tried to download and set it up using pip, but it hasn't worked.

I'm running a 10.9.5 OSx. The error that I'm currently getting is:

> No module named pybrain

Please help me with this problem. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install pybrain` in a Canopy Terminal suffices for me. After that, `import pybrain` succeeds.

Comment: Got that running. Thanks a lot